# Site edit 2009 compatibility with IE 11

Tags: siteedit-2009

In my company we have recently identified some apparent Site edit compatibility issues with IE 11. The main script is throwing an error, because the signature of the methods 'addListener' and 'addEventListener' have changed in IE 11, and I'm wondering if there is some official patch, supplied by SDL.

The issue is easy to fix, but I find always preferable to go for officially supported patches.

Comment: The title of your question says Site Edit 2009, but the body says Experience Manager.  Which product is it then?

Comment: Sorry Nickoli you're right. I have edited the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not expect an official fix for IE 11 & SiteEdit 2009 based on the supported browsers list found [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SiteEdit_2009_SP3&lang=en-US#docid=concept_348942E2877348318439C5D35F075176&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=Concept-ChangesToPrereqs.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_348942E2877348318439C5D35F075176) [login required]

Comment: You can always open a ticket with SDL to follow up on this, but we have indeed deprecated SiteEdit and don't intend to invest further in it... so chances are that we will not fix it